# Comma Delimited List

Tags: regex

I am looking for the regular expression I would need for a comma delimited list with spaces/commas at the start in order to validate it so I can remove the characters I don't want at certain parts of the string.

Example List

```
,  Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5,
```

However I would like to strip out certain parts of it to return like this

```
Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5
```

Comment: Why not use String.Remove API for removing 0th and N-1th char? May not be efficient if done repeatedly.

Comment: This is something that would be called over and over and I would prefer to do it using Regex :P I did try using the String.Remove function however sometimes the string building can get messed up and I'll end up with rogue white spaces (can't really be avoided.)

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: C# :P I have actually resolved my issue.. It was an issue with how I was writing my string opposed to how the string was being trimmed - Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way of doing it is without Regex

```
 var input = ",     Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item4,";
 var output = input.Trim(',',' ');
```